# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str when using nested dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, tf-idf

I'm creating an inverted index of text files stored locally using nested dictionaries. An abstract structure of the inverted index is below (the values are integer numbers). In any word value of key '0' is the idf and value of key '1' is the tf.

```
inverted_index={'word1':{'0':idf_value, '1': 2 , 'filename1': frequency_value, 'filename2': frequency_value},'word2':{'0':idf_value, '1': 2, 'filename1': frequency_value, 'filename2': frequency_value}}
```

And this is the code:

```
import textract, math, os
docs=[]
#Read the files and store them in docs
folder = os.listdir("./input/")
for file in folder:
    if file.endswith("txt"):
        docs.append ([file,textract.process("./input/"+file)])

inverted_index={}
for doc in docs:
    words=doc[1].decode()
    words=words.split(" ")

    #loop through and build the inverted index
    for word in words:
        temp={}
        #to remove initial white space
        if (word == " ") or (word==""):
            continue
        if word not in inverted_index:
            temp[doc[0]]=1
            temp['0']=0 #idf
            temp['1']=1 #tf
            inverted_index[word]=temp
        else:
            if doc[0] not in inverted_index[word].keys():
                inverted_index[word][doc[0]]=1
                inverted_index[word]['1']=inverted_index[word]['1']+1
            else:
                inverted_index[word][doc[0]]=inverted_index[word][doc[0]]+1

# to sort and print values with calculating the the tf and idf on the fly
for key, value in sorted(inverted_index.items()): # to sort words alphabitically
    inverted_index[key]=sorted(inverted_index[key]) # to sort the filenames where the word occured.
    inverted_index[key]['0']=math.log2(len(docs)/value['1']) # the error in this line
    print(key, value)
```

but I get this error in the second last line:

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aaaa.py", line 34, in <module>
    inverted_index[key]['0']=math.log2(len(docs)/value['1']) 
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

---

Can you please help me fix this bug. Thank you

Comment: Please post the full `Traceback`

Comment: Are the values of the inverted_index lists? If so, inverted_index[key]['1'] could be the problem. Try changing the indices in that line from '1' to 1 and '0' to 0, without the quotes.



Essentially, the error says that if you have a list `a = [1, 2, 3]`, then you can access items of the list by `a[0]` and not `a['0']`. String indices are not permitted.

Comment: I don't know the content of `inverted_index` but according to error try Changing `value['1']` to `value[1]` in the last second line.

Comment: I added the dictionary structure

Comment: You should update the question with full `Traceback` and content of dictionary. It'll be more clear to answer.

Comment: I did that. thanks

Comment: Please provide the content of `inverted_index` like `{'0':some_value,'1':some_value'}`

Comment: just as what @VijayK.Narayanan pointed it is because this error comes only when you try to access a list with an index that is not an integer or slices. The error is crystal clear try to change the string index to interger.

Comment: I'm not trying to access a list. They are nested dictionaries

Comment: Before the last `for` loop executes, print the `inverted_index`. You'll get the content

Comment: @ksai but what is the point of that ?? The purpose of the for loop is not just to print but also to calculate the idf values

Comment: The error lies in the structure of `inverted_index`. If there is no list in the `dict` then you must not get the error `list indices must be integers`

Comment: in fact `inverted_index[key]` created a list of your keys

Comment: @ShiftN'Tab you are right this new list contains the keys of the inner dictionary

Comment: @fsfr23 you made a big mistake you replace the dict object to a list of that object keys with inverted_index[key] = sorted(inverted_index[key]) thus it gives you confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error come from `inverted_index[key]['0']` since `inverted_index[key] = sorted(inverted_index[key])` created a list of your inner dict keys, and your

```
print(inverted_index[key])
# becomes ['0', '1', 'filename1', 'filename2']
```

And thus triggers the TypeError since you can't do string indexing to a list.

In order for you to change every word['0'] value of your inner dict you can try this code:

```
for key, value in sorted(inverted_index.items()):
    inverted_index[key] = sorted(inverted_index[key])
    current_word_key = inverted_index[key][0]
    value['0'] = 'some_value'
    inverted_index[key] = value  

print(inverted_index)
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://pythonfiddle.com/so-question-for-nested-indexing/)</kbd>

Comment: your code only show the list of keys for each word
for example:
'anger': ['0', '1', 'y10.txt']
it should be 'anger': {'0': 0, '1': 1, 'y10.txt': 1}

Comment: all i did is only point out what is wrong with this code, all you need is to assign value to back to its dict again nevertheless look for my update

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
for key, value in sorted(inverted_index.items()):
    inverted_index[key]=sorted(inverted_index[key])
    value['0']=math.log2(len(docs)/value['1']) # the error in this line
    inverted_index[key]=value
    print(key, value)
```

Comment: what? haha you just copied my answer and posted it on your own?

Comment: No, I did not copy it and you must have already updated it. Anyway, It's not a big deal I will accept your answer